# Making public posts via Facebook App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, posts

I recently noticed that posts from my app were going to all-friends even when I requested they be public.  Through the response to my bug report (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/191063590970288) I learned about the "App activity privacy" setting buried in the user privacy settings but I don't see anything in the FB developer docs about this.  Even if it's not something an app can request a default permission for, it would be nice if there was some mention of it on the privacy or post documentation pages.

Anyway, does anyone out there know of a way to request "public post" permissions?

Comment: I think it defaulted to the user's default privacy setting (at least it did for me) and on the permissions dialog there's a selector when granting publishing permissions to set the maximum the app is allowed to set

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to set privacy for newly created Album](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7125614/unable-to-set-privacy-for-newly-created-album)

Answer (score 2):

Go to your FB app - Privacy Settings - Who can see your future post - Set " Public" as the audience.

By default this is set as "Only Me". Hope this will help.

Comment: I enter in 'App Details', click on button 'Configure App Center Permissions' on 'App Center Listed Platforms' section and change the option 'Default Activity Privacy' to 'Public'. Unfortunately, old users were not affected.