# How to get FB application posts to be public and link clickable?

Tags: facebook, settings, public, privacy, posts

I have created a FB app (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/566403306788175) that posts to my FB profile through an external system called Social Oomph. Although the settings on my FB profile are set to Public, the posts from the app are appearing to Friends only.

**I cannot see a way inside the FB app itself to set the posts to be Public. How can I do this?**

I found this topic that appears to be related but is perhaps out of date, since I can't find any "App activity privacy": [Making public posts via Facebook App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879957/making-public-posts-via-facebook-app) nor can I find any reference to Privacy Settings within the app either.

**On a related note, the name of my application (which displays under every post the app makes) is not clickable,** though I have specified a site URL for the app on the basic settings page.

How can I make sure the link for this app is clickable?

Thanks in advance for any insights anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the app setting is set to Fiends I guess. Also, whatever setting user has chose for an app remains for all the apps that he is going to authorize in future until he changes the one.

But its possible to change the privacy setting of a feed through Graph API, you can add additional parameter- `privacy` with your `/me/feed` call. I'm not sure what sdk or language are you using but you can just add this extra parameter with your call-

Parameter: `privacy`

Value: `EVERYONE`

[More details here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/)

#### Please Note

Since a  user can also manually sets the privacy of an applicationfrom here- [Facebook Settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)- the actual privacy applied will be the **more restrictive privacy setting** between the two.

**eg.** 
If the user has set "*Only Me*" in the facebook settings, but in app you applied "*Public*", then the user's preference, i.e.  *Only Me* will be used. 

But if the user has set "*Public*" in the app settings, but in the app you applied "*Friends*", then the app's setting i.e. "*Friends*" is used, as it's more restrictive than the User's settings.

Hope that helps.